# UI of IPA server is not coming up on AWS ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ipa, freeipa

I have installed the IPA server on AWS EC2 instance by the following method:

1. Updated the /etc/hosts file
2. Installed the software:

   ```
   yum install ipa-server ip-server-dns bind bind-dyndb-ldap yum install ipa-server-dns
   ```
3. iptables --flush
4. firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port={80/tcp,443/tcp,389/tcp,636/tcp,88/tcp,464/tcp,53/tcp,88/udp,464/udp,53/udp,123/udp}

   ```
   firewall-cmd --reload
   ```
5. Ran the following command:

   ```
   ipa-server-install —setup-dns
   ```

After successful installation ran kinit admin

I am still unable to see the ui in my browser.

When I checked it found out that dirsrv and ipa_memcached services are not running. How can I enable those services and see the IPA server UI?

Comment: The main problem of enabling freeIPA in EC2, is that every machine in EC2 has at least two kinds of of IP addresses. One is internal to the VPC only, e.g. the default VPC use IP addresses starting from 172.31.*.*; Another kinds of IP addresses are public IP addresses, which are different from the internal ones. A default install of freeIPA server and clients in EC2 will not work due to this dual IP addresses.

Comment: To install freeIPA, we first need to configure individual hosts' /etc/hosts, /etc/hostname files, so they point to the full qualified DNS name of the hosts. After that, we are ready to add these names to DNS servers.

Comment: bypass freeIPA's own DNS services, and use AWS Route53 DNS service that should solve your problem